# Uso correcto de modelos en Symfony al necesitar Querys complejas

Tags: php, pdo, symfony3

Soy muy nuevo en Symfony, estuve viendo la documentación respecto a los modelos, y todos los ejemplos e indicaciones hacen mucho hincapié en entidades (`Entities`) que están bien definidas en la DB. Mi problema es que el sistema que estoy haciendo requiere de muchas consultas del tipo

```
SELECT [MUCHOS CAMPOS, FUNCIONES CONCAT, CONDICIONES CASE, ETC] FROM TABLA_1
INNER JOIN TABLA_2 ...
INNER JOIN UNA_VISTA ...
```

Por lo que estoy medio desorientado sobre que entidad tendría que declarar (por el momento me estoy manejando haciendo las consultas desde el controlador, pero la idea es respetar el modelo MVC).

¿Hago una entidad de tabla 1 y hago todas las consultas en su clase haciendo INNER JOIN con las otras tablas sin que estas últimas tengan entidades o debo crearlas para todas? ¿Es necesario un repositorio, 3 (uno para cada entidad) o ninguno y hago las consultas desde una de las entidades directamente?

Aclaración: la `TABLA_2` y `UNA_VISTA` no tienen consultas de ellas mismas de forma aislada, es decir, no tengo ninguna consulta en el código del tipo

```
SELECT [CAMPOS DE LA TABLA_2] FROM TABLA_2
```

Por lo que no sé qué tanto valga la pena declarar entidades para ambas.

Si pudieran darme una mano, aunque sea una pequeña guía se los agradecería muchísimo. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes...

1. Deberías tener una entidad por cada tabla o vista de tu modelo de datos.
2. Aunque no hagas consultas directamente sobre `TABLA_2` o `UNA_VISTA`, es necesario que estén modeladas para que el ORM sepa cómo mapear sus campos, ya que van a ser usadas como elementos dentro de otra consulta (mediante `inner join`)
3. El repositorio es una clase útil donde poder alojar todo el código relacionado con operaciones con un modelo o entidad, por lo general, es una buena idea tener este tipo de operaciones centralizadas, hace que el código sea más reusable.
4. En `doctrine`, las entidades son objetos que representan a tus modelos de datos, no son el lugar donde hacer consultas. De hecho, no están dotadas de las herramientas necesarias para que las hagas, esto debería hacerse en un repositorio.
5. Puedes configurar las relaciones de una entidad con otras entidades para que el ORM incluya automáticamente un `INNER JOIN`. Esto se hace con una directiva llamada `fetch`, que dependiendo del tipo de relación puede adoptar los valores: `eager`, `lazy` o `extra_lazy`. Por defecto, su valor es `lazy`, que hará que el ORM precargue las relaciones de una entidad, pero sin consultar dichos valores estrictamente. El valor `eager` fuerza al ORM a traer los datos de las relaciones de una entidad, normalmente a través de un `INNER JOIN`. Si en tus consultas a `TABLA_1` vas a usar como criterios únicamente campos de `TABLA_1`, esta configuración te servirá. Si necesitas hacer uso de más campos, tendrás que generar un repositorio para esta tabla y generar tu propio método find con los campos necesarios. Dentro de este método puedes usar el [QueryBuilder](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) de `doctrine` o [DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)
6. Con un ORM como `doctrine`, no realizas consultas de campos concatenados o condiciones case. En su lugar, extraes entidades, y son dichas entidades las que tienen un método que devuelven los valor de los campos formateados como necesites.
7. Mantén el controlador lo más simple posible. Consulta entidades en una clase de tipo repositorio o crea servicios donde alojar la lógica de negocio. Debes ver el controlador como una mera capa de interacción HTTP (Recibe `Request` y emite `Response`, únicamente)

Comment: Excelente! Más claro imposible! Muchas gracias